# Why does my media query have no effect on my CSS?

Tags: php, html, css, media-queries

I'm making a counter that is contained within a box. I'm trying to make this counter responsive to different screen sizes, but the media query I'm trying to use will not work for some reason.

I have tried changing the the device width to below 768px but the query has no effect on the counter and I'm not sure why. I have included the HTML/PHP code for the counter as well as the CSS. Can anybody figure out why it's not working

I have made sure this tag is included in the head of the document.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Code:

```css
  .wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  float: center
}

.counter-container {
  top: 14vh;
  right: 4%;
  float: right;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border-radius: 4%;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  color: white;
}

.counter {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.count-title {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 70px;
}

.count-text {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 5px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.count-dial {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 8px 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.counter-closer {
  float: right;
  margin: 2px 6px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.counter-closer:hover {
  -webkit-filter: invert(1);
  filter: invert(1);
}

.counter-digit {
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(153, 255, 102), rgb(0, 255, 0));
  border-radius: 5%;
  color: rgb(0, 128, 0);
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.counter-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.bottle-icon {
  width: 38px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

.rotate-bottle {
  transform: rotate(25deg);
  -webkit-animation: shake .5s ease-in-out .1s infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes shake {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(35deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(25deg);
  }
```

```html
<div class="counter col_fourth counter-container" id="bottleCounter">
  <i class="fas fa-times counter-closer" onclick="closeCounter()"></i>
  <div class="counter-row">
    <!--NB 19.11.21 green bottle image next to counter-->
    <img class="bottle-icon rotate-bottle" src="https://img.resultclothing.net/icons/Green_Bottle.png" alt="water bottle">
    <h2 class="count-title count-number">
      <?php 
            $bottleCount = str_split(intval($var)); 
        echo '
        <span class="timer counter-digit" data-to="'.$bottleCount[0].'" data-speed="5000"></span>
        <span class="timer counter-digit" data-to="'.$bottleCount[1].'" data-speed="5000"></span>
        <span class="timer counter-digit" data-to="'.$bottleCount[2].'" data-speed="5000"></span>
        <span class="timer counter-digit" data-to="'.$bottleCount[3].'" data-speed="5000"></span>
        <span class="timer counter-digit" data-to="'.$bottleCount[4].'" data-speed="5000"></span>
        <span class="timer counter-digit" data-to="'.$bottleCount[5].'" data-speed="5000"></span>
        <span class="timer counter-digit" data-to="'.$bottleCount[6].'" data-speed="5000"></span>';
        ?>
    </h2>
  </div>
  <p class="count-text">
    <?php echo constant('LANG_FOOTER_BOTTLES_REC'); ?>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please Provide your all code ,including html ;-)

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I recommend all new users visit [ask] for tips on how to get the most out of SO.   Please note that if you include a [mcve] it will make it much easier for the community to understand your issue and, in turn, provide you with helpful guidance.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: @MarioG8 I have added more of the code. I can't add all of it because it's quite a large document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**the missing closing bracket**

Add the closing bracket to you keyframe

```
    @-webkit-keyframes shake {
        from{
            -webkit-transform: rotate(35deg);
        }
        to {
            -webkit-transform:rotate(15deg);
            -webkit-transform:rotate(25deg);   
      } 
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I've added the full code now before was just a snippet. Does it still work on yours with my updated code?

Comment: @Nbaker99 ok. i checked. It works in my example. but it works only when the media-query declaration is above the keyframe declaration. If it will below then the media query doesnt work.

Comment: by the way. Nice shaked bottle. i like it :-)

Comment: SOLUTION: the missing closing bracket in your keyframe `to {}`

Comment: Yes it works now! Thank you kind sir, you have been very helpful. Thank you for the comment about my animation as well, it is very simple but I like it!

Comment: @Nbaker99 You welcome Nbaker99!